# Adjectival form of "foreign policy"?

Tags: word-usage, derivational-morphology

Is there a adjectival form of "foreign policy" or "foreign relations"? It needs to fit in with:

> There were contrasting political, social, and *???* systems.

EDIT: By "foreign policy", I really mean "military relations", not diplomatic.

Comment: Can you give us some more examples of what kinds of policy or doctrine must  be characterized by this word? As a comment on Daniel's answer, you gave "*isolationism*", and "*being composed of fighting city-states*" (which really isn't a *policy*, whether foreign, military, or diplomatic, but a *description* of a nation), and you mentioned "diplomatic" doesn't really cover those. Do you have more examples?

Comment: What's wrong with just using _foreign policy_ as a noun adjunct?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: That would be the answer with an explanation. For example, Finnish has a word for the adjective form: [_ulkopoliittinen_](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ulkopoliittinen). But in English, it is used as a noun adjunct.

Comment: @ermanen Many other Germanic languages have similar adjectives, too (_udenrigspolitisk_ in Danish, _utenrikspolitisk_ in Norwegian, etc.), and others don't (Icelandic has to form compounds with _utanrikíkisstefnu-_, for example).

Comment: @epicfaace: Diplomacy does include military relations/negotiations. Are you emphasizing that the relations are friendly? Friendly military relations is called an alliance. I think we need more context than that sentence. What are you contrasting? The two countries?

Comment: I'm contrasting two countries (Mesopotamia and Egypt).
In the first country, there are multiple city-states who fight and vie for power.
In the second one, affairs are usually isolationist.

What category would this fit in?

Comment: OK, then you're not talking about the relations *between* Mesopotamia and Egypt? You're talking about the relations *within* the two countries respectively, so you can contrast them. But that's domestic politics, not foreign. Am I right? I'm confused because isolationism is a foreign policy (how one nation interacts with other nations), and city-state politics is domestic (how the nation is politically infrastructured).

Comment: If you're talking about relations *between* countries A and B, how they interact with each other, this is diplomacy (whether military or not). If you're talking about relations *within* country A and comparing them to relations *within* country B, this is simply political infrastructure.

Comment: If you insert a hyphen into the compound noun 'foreign policy' thus: *foreign-policy*, it becomes a regularly-formed adjective. Hence your query sentence becomes "There were contrasting political, social and foreign-policy systems." (If you're actually including this in a piece you're writing, consider replacing 'systems' with 'structures'.)

Answer (score 3):

*Diplomatic* is the word you want here. [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/diplomatic):

> **adjective**
> **1.** of, pertaining to, or engaged in diplomacy:
> *diplomatic officials.*

[Diplomacy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/diplomacy):

> **noun**
> **1.** the conduct by government officials of negotiations and other relations between nations.
>
> **2.** the art or science of conducting such negotiations.

So your example sentence would be completed as follows:

> There were contrasting political, social, and diplomatic systems.

Comment: "Diplomatic" makes it seem like it's just about diplomacy, but I meant to talk about military relations. (The first country is isolationist, and the second is composed of fighting city-states). Would diplomatic still be appropriate in this case?

Comment: Yes, diplomacy refers to all international relations, including military. But there's a point I'm also not sure on: in your sentence, are you "contrasting" the two nations' systems? If so, you aren't referrinf to their relationship, you're considering them separately in order to compare them. In that case, if you mean *military*, I suggest you use *military system*.  But maybe that's not the larger context.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've clarified you're looking for a word which describes "*military* relations", perhaps "***martial***" would suit:

> [***martial***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/martial): *relating to fighting or war*.

Comment: And your projected relationships could take the form of a *martial plan*?

Comment: And if you joined another nation wage war as an ally, you've given "*martial aid*" (sorry, couldn't help myself).

Comment: Hey Dan - I voted this down too, to emphasise the insane voting seen on this site !   Whoo!

Comment: Have a party guys! Let the voice of the people be heard!

Comment: Please be aware, before this daft conversation goes any further, that *foreign policy, military policy, and diplomacy* are three quite different things.

Comment: @WS2: which would you recommend, given OP's examples on Daniel's answer?

Comment: @DanBron I would amend the OP's sentence to read: 'There were contrasting political and social systems, as well as military policies'.

Comment: @WS2 Curious, what distinction would you draw between *foreign policy* and *diplomacy*?

Comment: @Daniel '*Foreign policy*' means the overall policy of the government in foreign affairs, or the policy towards one particular area or issue. For example you might say 'Current British foreign policy in Syria and Iraq is to oppose ISIS forces whilst forswearing any alliance, or working with the Assad government'. *Diplomacy* refers to the detailed work of officials (diplomats) with foreign governments and other parties, in order to give effect to the government's policies.

Comment: So policy is the theoretical, and diplomacy the practical aspect of foreign relations? I get that, but to my mind diplomacy includes policy to some extent, possibly fully.

Comment: @bib There should be an onsite groan tally.

Answer (score 0):

[strategic](https://www.google.ie/search?q=define%3Astrategic&oq=define%3Astrategic):

> adjective
>
> 1. relating to the identification of long-term or overall aims and interests and the means of achieving them.
>    "strategic planning for the organization is the responsibility of top management"
>    synonyms:   planned, calculated, deliberate; More
>    antonyms:   random
>    designed or planned to serve a particular purpose.
>    "alarms are positioned at strategic points around the prison"
>
>    relating to the gaining of overall or long-term military advantage.
>    "Newark Castle was of strategic importance"